# Why is Default not implemented for Mutex, RWLock, CondVar, Duration?

Tags: rust

The `Default` trait can be `#[derive(..)]`d only if the contents of the deriving type also implement `Default`. This means the trait gets easier to use the more it is implemented. However, I notice some types from `std` are missing implementations, although they have perfectly valid defaults (sometimes depending on generic params).

- `Mutex<T>` and `RWLock<T>` could implement by `new(_)` (`where T: Default`)
- `CondVar` could simply implement by `CondVar::new()`
- `Duration` could derive (to get a zero duration, <s>which is a sensible default</s>)

Is there a technical reason for those omissions?

Comment: I'd disagree with *a zero duration, which is a sensible default*, but the others, sure.

Comment: Why? Do you think that there is no sensible default at all or do you think there's a more sensible one?

Comment: I'd say there is no sensible default. Most of the times I think about duration in regards to timeouts, and a timeout of zero doesn't make sense to me and neither would picking any other value. Although I do see that numbers implement `Default` as `0`, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @Shepmaster: An in-house framework I use has a default timeout of 0. Strangely enough if you forget to override it the reply generally does not come fast enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people have asked a similar question with `Debug` implementations, see [“Missing Debug Implementations — #31869”](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31869) which can also only be deriving under similar conditions as `Default`.

Unfortunately the corresponding PR “[libcore: add Debug implementations to most missing types #32054](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32054)” seems to suggest that some types were not `Debug` simply because no-one had written a `Debug` implementation for them. Some other types are kind of controversial about what the implementation should do and there is some fear about adding them in the standard library.

It reasonable to assume that at least some types are not `Default` for the same non-technical reasons.

Comment: There's issue #31865 (at least for CondVar, I made a note of the others). I've pushed [PR #32807](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32807)